# Malware Execution Delay

Tags: malware, tools, dynamic-analysis

I am new to malware analysis and am currently using Cuckoo to understand some of the basics.

I am trying to figure the time that the malware delays its initial executions. I found a functional call `NtDelayExecution` in the API/System calls that had two parameters: `Status => Skipped` and `Milliseconds => 1000`. The status of the function call reads `SUCCESS`.

What does the argument `Status` mean? Does it mean that the call was skipped? Because there are other calls to `NtDelayExecution` that do not have the argument `Status`.

Answer (score 1):

Cuckoo is an automated sandbox meant for malware analysis. It skips the first N seconds of delay functions when a program starts.

NtDelayExecutiom is commonly used to prevent dynamic malware analysis, so it's skipped at program start to prevent the analysis from taking a prohibitively long time.

The function call output is letting you know it skipped a 1000 millisecond delay (1000ms = 1 second).